# Dependency change results in missing reference to the old file

Tags: c#, msbuild

It happened I am responsible for maintaining an older C# application. The application connects to a MySQL server and for some reason the MySql.Data.dll was included on disk and checked in.

So I thought on changing this to reference using a NuGET package. I removed the dependency on the checked in binary and added a package reference.

Now when I build the application I get the following error:

```
"path\myproject.csproj" (build target) (1) ->
       (GenerateApplicationManifest target) -> 
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3987,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'lib\MySql.Data.dll'.
```

I tried to find any occurrence of that dll but there seems to be no reference anymore.

How to stop the project referencing the non existing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that even though I removed the dll within Rider the deployment reference (<Content ...) within the csproj file was not removed.